# Getting values after foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that gives me a number of values after looping through an array, like so:

842,844,841,839,838

This is the loop:

```
foreach ($values as $valuesKey => $value) {     
    echo $valuesKey . ',';
}
```

I need to work with those values after the loop finishes, how can I go about it? I want to put the list of values into another function. Is this even possible??

```
do_shortcode('[playlist type="audio" ids="/* values should go here */"][/playlist]');
```

It's supposed to look like this if it works:

```
do_shortcode('[playlist type="audio" ids="842,844,841,839,838"][/playlist]');
```

Thanks for anyone who can point me into the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a loop. You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to join the array keys into a comma-separated string:

```
do_shortcode('[playlist type="audio" ids="'.implode(',', array_keys($values)).'"][/playlist]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
implode(",", array_keys($values))
```

Comment: +1 since I missed the fact that these were actually array keys, and not values. You reminded me.

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
$val = array(); 
foreach ($values as $valuesKey => $value) {     
   $val[] = $valuesKey;
}
$val = implode(",", $val);
do_shortcode('[playlist type="audio" ids="'.$val.'"][/playlist]');
```